# Problems with opening/saving attachment in e-mail as .docx file

Tags: email, attachment

When I want to open an attachment (a .docx file) in an e-mail (Google Chrome) it automatically gets downloaded and saved as a .ashx file. How can I open this as a .docx file and be able to edit it?

Comment: did you try renaming the downloaded file's extension into .docx?

Answer (score 0):

If you do a search on the internet this issue is incredibly common and there is no definitive fix. The best solution I have found is as stated to change the filename and then the extension to .docx or whatever extension the original file was. The problem is NOT exclusive to Google Chrome.